# FileNotFoundError Installing PyQt5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, installation

I'm been trying to install PyQt and I can't get past the below error. I've read a few posts suggesting that I should upgrade PIP, setup_tools, and ez_install. I've tried all of that with no luck. Any tips?

```
c:\Python27>pip install PyQt5_gpl-5.10.tar.gz
Processing c:\python27\pyqt5_gpl-5.10.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\JAME~1.KRK\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-0u8uht47-build\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JAME~1.KRK\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0u8uht47-build\
```

Same thing in 3.6:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32>pip install PyQt5_gpl-5.10.tar.gz
Processing c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\pyqt5_gpl-5.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\JAME~1.KRK\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-f9s0_6sp-build\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\JAM~1.KRK\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-f9s0_6sp-build\
```

Comment: I had the exact same error, but with `pip3 install PyQt5`.  I updated pip `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and tried again.  After the update I got a more verbose error letting me know that the problem was to do with permissions.  Changing to a user install solved my problem `pip3 install --user PyQt5`.  I'm running Ubuntu... so I'm not sure how helpful this is for windows users...

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered the same issue and find clue in the topic. It has been solved by pip upgrade.

**Here is the detail:**

**1. Issue case:**

pip3 install pyqt5.

failed and report FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

**2. OS environment:**

```
Win10 64x WSL2
```

**3. Python environment**

```
python 3.7.3

pip version 19.X (not write down)
```

****Solved steps:****

1. pip3 install --upgrade pip
2. pip3 install --user PyQt5
3. sudo apt-get update -y
4. sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y

now. It works.

Root cause:

**a. pyqt**
in wsl, pip old version download wrong package.
pip (v20.x) download below version
PyQt5-5.15.2-5.15.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

**b. libgl1.so1.**
not such lib need install by apt intall

Hope my experience can help you.

Comment: Thank you! I've solved the issue updating pip (from pip 18.1 to pip 21.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

On [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.10) it seems PyQT5 is for python 3.5 or higher only. Not python 2.7. Use an earlier version of PyQt or a newer version of python (Python 2.7 isn't supported beyond 2020, you'll need to move sooner or later).

Comment: I actually did upgrade and got the same error on 3.6

Comment: Weird. Well I recommend downloading a distribution that's already done all that for you like anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to make `pip` install the `PyQt5` *source archive*. `PyQt` doesn't use the usual `setup.py` script that many python packages use and cannot be built and installed from source with `pip`. Furthermore, the `.tar.gz` format is intended for linux systems and Windows provides no native support. I am not sure whether `pip` on Windows would even handle the format. There is a `.zip` version provided for Windows users.

You need to either extract the archive and [build from source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source), or allow `pip` to download and install the package itself with `pip install PyQt5`.

If you are using Python < 3.5, you will have to build from source (or install `PyQt4` instead), as there are no official builds provided for these versions of Python. For everything else the `pip` command above should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Python >= 3.5 or try the older PyQt4

Answer (score 0):

on debianoids there is a nice way out of this bug

```
apt install python3-pyqt5
```